# How to compute the MIN, MAX, AVG of all rows in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, max, average, min

I have a MySQL table that contains measurements data. For example:

```
# name, time
first, 0.0013
second, 0.0015
third, 0.0012
fourth, 0.0019
```

I want to compute the MAX, MIN and AVG of all rows. So the results of the above example should be:

```
MIN: 0.0012 
MAX: 0.0019 
AVG: 0.001475
```

I am aware of MIN, MAX, and AVG MYSQL functions. But they return the result of a single field. I need aggregated results similar to COUNT function.

**EDIT:**

It is not necessary for me to get all the 3 functions results in one query. It is fine to have 3 different queries. The main problem is how to aggregate the, say, MAX of all rows as I illustrated in the example.

Comment: You can't declare different function results of the same column in different rows for the same query in any good way. For that you'd need to do 3 separate queries, each with the `AVG`, `MIN` and `MAX` function. The best approach is to store the results in different columns, ie `SELECT AVG(time), MAX(time), MIN(time) from ...`

Comment: @Mohammad the link asks about aggregated columns. In my case I want aggregated rows, not columns.

Comment: @Johan  that's fine. But how to get the MAX for example for all the rows in a table?

Comment: I updated my comment to include an example just before I saw your question, but for the sense of chronological order I'll paste it here too :) `SELECT AVG(time), MAX(time), MIN(time) from ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mind having it in different queries? Then you can aggregate easily without any hassle.

```
SELECT MIN(time) AS minimum FROM <tablename>

SELECT MAX(time) AS minimum FROM <tablename>

SELECT AVG(time) AS minimum FROM <tablename>
```

Edit: This can be summarized without issues into a single query, too.

```
SELECT MIN(time) AS minimum, MAX(time) AS maximum, AVG(time) AS average FROM <tablename>
```

I was not aware that multiple columns could be returned while using an aggregator without grouping. Nice special case here. Thanks for clarification by [Johan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10400050/johan) and [HoldOffHunger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2430549/holdoffhunger).

Comment: It works but there is a small issue though. The `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG` returns larger numbers than that in the table. For example, this is the actual maximum number in the table: `0.00348675`. Somehow, `MAX` returns this: `0.0034867459908127785`. Any idea how to get accurate results?

Comment: @user9371654 That's because floating point numbers are inexact. Use `DECIMAL` if you want exact fractions.

Comment: @MatthiasBö: Could you please cite your sources if you borrow from other answers?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly from our comments I believe this is what you're looking for and should do it in one query.

```
SELECT 
    MIN(time) AS minimum, 
    MAX(time) AS maximum, 
    AVG(time) AS average
FROM t;
```

Comment: Is that going to work though? From what I learned, you cannot return an aggretation value alongside anything else without grouping by the other values. I've never tried aggerating multiple times in one query tbh...

Comment: There is also a small parenthesis error in the MIN line - closing bracket should be before AS

Comment: As long as it's the same set it doesn't matter. If we wanted to use min and max on different groupings it wouldn't work. Or if we wanted other values that aren't computed into a single row it wouldn't work either. Edit: Fixed the typo, thanks :)

Comment: Tested on my server, works just fine, `select MIN(id), MAX(id), AVG(id) from Paper; |    1000 |    2078 | 1539.0000 |`.  This was easy to verify: `select SUM(id) / (COUNT(id)) from Paper;  |             1539.0000 |`.  This should be accepted answer.

Comment: @Johan thanks for clarifying this. Sometimes these "textbook-rules" are just not precise enough ;)

Comment: I know the feeling, spent half a year learning databases, yet the best knowledge I got was from working with and using them :)

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
  select ROW_NUMBER(), least(first, second, third, fourth) as min, 
   greatest(first, second, third, fourth) as max,
  (first+ second+ third+ fourth)/4 as avg
  from table t;
```

then if you need avg of all rows you can write another query to compute it from this result.

Comment: thanks. But my table contains thousands of records. This `first, second, third, fourth` is just in my small example. But I can not enumerate thousands of rows in a query.

Comment: For example, in count, we use `COUNT(column_name)`. This provide aggregated result for all rows in the column specified.